How to type hint a method returning a list of generic dataclass instances?
I was wondering if it was possible to get a Union return type for get_bars in this scenario using pyright:
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Bar[T]:
    a: T

@dataclass
class Foo:
    bars: list[Bar]

    def get_bars(self):
        return self.bars

I'm not sure on how to type bars in Foo (or which TypeVar pass to Foo), the idea would be that get_bars should return a Union of Bar[T] for instance
foo = Foo(bars=[Bar[int](a=1), Bar[str](a='bar')])
foo.get_bars()  # Should be inferred as a list[Bar[int] | Bar[str]]


Please add a typechecker tag - mypy? Pyright? Pyright infers unions in such cases, so that's easier: https://pyright-play.net/?code=GYJw9gtgBAJghgFzgYwDZwM4YKYagSwgAcwQFZEV0sAoUSKBATyPwDsBzA408gFRbYAanBAAaKAHFsbbCHzIaNPlAC8UAUWGiAFACI%2BegJTKA%2BsjBqNgkSH19zYPRIsA3UfjhsEqviACu2CZKAALwSGiYGDSRWFAAQrrSsvLIANoOFgC6RgBcNFCFUHC5Go6h4VRRMdR4AGJgYDrJcgoZOflFUABGohilqPgYCGmJIO1ZSl0w2MBQHNgIpr0gGDo4qMBGUAC0AHxQg8OjohOdXUUgi-4gbFAbwAB0K9F0jVYNTS%2BqJ%2BPsCFkdHBVABGIwSMZpYYgQHAgDkKzhRhyNCurmwcFQpmYWh0wEajwWSxeOiMRiAA Mypy infers intersections, so you'd need to add manual annotation.

@InSync why remove [tag:python-3.12]? It's a relatively new syntax, I think versioned tag is relevant here.

@STerliakov This question, as far as I can see, does not have anything specific to the new syntax; it would remain the same even if you were to replace the code with its 3.11-or-lower equivalent. Also, typing features are backported, so the Python version is irrelevant most of the times.

afaik this code would not run in previous version, that's why I added the tag (we had to inherit Generic before)

Still, that does not make this question not useful for other versions. It's the problem, rather than the features used, that defines the question. Even more so when, as stated, such features are backported and/or can be replaced with equivalents.

get_bars has to return a list type, like list[Bar[int] | Bar[str]].
